# aria-labelledby attribute and asp.net validators

Tags: asp.net, validation, accessibility

I'm creating an html5 site in VS2010 using .net 4.0 and the stock validators.  To make the validators accessible I've added an *aria-labelledby* to the associated textbox and set the validators id in the aria-labelledby value. The validators have their id mode set to static.  Validation labels are hidden by display:none css styling, which is removed when triggered.

Seems to work fine, as **NVDA** sees the error message and is associating it to the proper text box.  But when I go to validate it I get the following error:

**aria-labelledby attribute must point to an element in the same document**

So, the question is ... can the *aria-labelledby* reference a control that is not visible?

Comment: `display: hidden`? I suppose you mean `visibility: hidden` or `display: none` (both hide content from screen readers so it could be any of them). Would it make sense to hide visually this "validator" by [placing it off screen](http://webaim.org/techniques/css/invisiblecontent/) (negative text-indent or huge value of left displacement with position: relative)?

Comment: Yikes ... that's embarrassing ... it s display:none now.  As for hiding it, the error is used for sighted users too.  Actually that's the original viewer.  I'm trying to adapt the validators to be accessible to screen readers too.

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer is yes ... after some more testing I found out that NVDA will read the hidden span tag that is the validator error text.

The issue I was having was in making a required validator have its error message receivable by NVDA.  Unfortunately the error is shown after the IsValid function is fired ... making the event fire after a postback.  NVDA would see the page with the error messages, but not know that they were new.

To fix it I'm firing the validator on the blur event, as shown below.

I added a blur event to the control being validated, and called the validator attached to that control

```
onblur="validateControl(RequiredFieldValidatorID)"
```

The function called uses the ValidatorValidate function.

```
function validateControl(n) {
 ValidatorValidate(n);
}
```

This makes a required validator fire on blur.  Still need to refocus on the control that has an error, but I think I'll need to catch the tab and redirect ... work in progress.